# Deployment through Jenkins

Tags: ssh, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I have two jobs in Jenkins. One for build and the other for deployment.
Once the build job is successful i create a build tag and publish it on Github.

Next i take that tag and deploy those artifacts using **publish over ssh plugin** and selecting the option **send files or execute commands over ssh** as my post build step. I am also adding the already configured server at this step.

Now my concern is in some cases server details are not informed i.e username/password well in advance.

Is there a feature in Jenkins which can ask me to enter servername/username/password for deploying? Can i have a parametrized build having these 3 fields as inputs? So that when i click "build now" in deployment job it asks for these fields.

Answer (score 0):

The publish over SSH plugin is designed to use credentials previously setup and managed by Jenkins. This is necessary because Jenkins managed the distribution of credentials when you run builds on slave nodes.

As an alternative solution that you could consider is using the [Rundeck plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RunDeck+Plugin). [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) is an general purpose automation tool, similar to Jenkins but focused on general purpose automation. The advantage is that you can use dedicated tools for build and deployment (useful when you have separate Dev and Ops teams) and Rundeck is better suited to managing large numbers of run-time servers.

Comment: Mark i agree with your response on how the SSH Plugin works. But in my case its not possible to install another application and i need to achieve the same using Jenkins only.
If there is a batch script which connects and executes command using SSH taking in only username and password as parameters then it will help me out too.